# Mock Xrm.Page for client-side TypeScript development in Dynamics CRM

Tags: typescript, tdd, dynamics-crm

Is it possible to approach the development of client-side customisations for Dynamics CRM using TypeScript and a test-driven development process?

My understanding is that to make this possible, a library must have been written in TypeScript which mocks the [Xrm.Page object model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328474.aspx). Does such a library exist?

I've looked into some Xrm mocking libraries such as [this one](https://github.com/ambek/XrmPage-Mock) though my research so far has only found libraries written in JavaScript.

Answer (score 3):

I personally use this tool [Delegate.XrmDefinitelyTyped](http://delegateas.github.io/Delegate.XrmDefinitelyTyped/), which is open-source tool on [GitHub](https://github.com/delegateas/Delegate.XrmDefinitelyTyped). It works similar to CrmSvcUtil - simply allows you to generate proxy classes for entities, forms etc. Of course it also generates whole Xrm.Page object model for you.

From the tool description:

> It is the TypeScript equivalent of CrmSvcUtil, but instead of
> generating early-bound .NET classes for server-side code, it generates
> TypeScript interfaces for all your client-side coding.
>
> It generates data-specific declaration files for:
>
> The Xrm object model for client-side coding of forms and custom pages
>
> Global and entity-specific option sets
>
> The standard SDK.REST.js API
> for querying CRM via OData.
>
> The standard SDK.MetaData.js API for
> querying the metadata of CRM.
>
> XrmQuery for the Web API and the old
> REST endpoint. XrmQuery makes it possible to perform fully type-safe
> queries to CRM.